# Error when executing `floor_date()`

Tags: r, lubridate

I get the following error message:

```
Error in if (sum(c(new$hour, new$min, new$sec))) { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
```

when I execute the following code:

```
keep$EstimateDate <- as.Date(keep$date + keep$days,"%Y-%m-%d")
keep$EstimateDateWeekStart <- floor_date(keep$EstimateDate,"week") #+1
```

The `keep$EstimateDate` is a column in a data.table with properly formatted dates.

The `floor_date()` is a function in the `lubridate` package.

Comment: It's really almost impossible for anyone to help unless we can run a snippet of reproducible code that generates this error. Try providing the output of `dput(head(keep))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only scenario I can think of where you get an error in `if` but don't in `sum`, is when you have an `NA` in your sum. With that in mind, this is most likely what's happening:

```
floor_date(as.Date(NA), "week")
#Error in if (sum(c(new$hour, new$min, new$sec))) { : 
#  argument is not interpretable as logical
```

In other words, check that you don't have any `NA`'s.

Comment: I suspect that this has caused the error in my dataset. It is not always easy to discover those things in a large dataset like mine (approx 4 million rows).