# Add ticks to a line plot and group the ticks by a variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a multi-line plot which shows revenue for 20 customers in the form of various lines.

I used the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
trainingSummary <- top20CustomersRevenue %>% group_by(custno, TrainingDate) %>%
  summarize(Revenue = first(Revenue),
            TrainingType = first(TrainingType))
trainingSummary$TrainingType <- as.factor(trainingSummary$TrainingType)

p <- ggplot() + geom_line(data=top20CustomersRevenue,aes(x=DeltaMonth,y=Revenue,group=custno),alpha=0.3) +
  theme_bw() +
  ylab('Revenue (Dollars)') + xlab('') + theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_text(hjust=0, angle=0), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=1, angle=45),plot.title=element_text(size=20))
p <- p + geom_point(data = trainingSummary,
               aes(x = TrainingDate, y = Revenue, color= TrainingType))
p
```

and got the following plot:

[image]

I have the data in the following format:

```
custno  TrainingType    Revenue TrainingDate    DeltaMonth
250 Webinar 4146.80 2013-02-26  2013-01-01
250 Webinar 6211.93 2013-02-26  2013-02-01
250 Webinar 2199.72 2013-02-26  2013-03-01
250 Webinar 4452.65 2013-02-26  2013-04-01
250 Webinar 4787.83 2013-02-26  2013-05-01
250 Webinar 4004.80 2013-02-26  2013-06-01
250 Webinar 4806.69 2013-02-26  2013-07-01
```

Example - In the above dataset, I would like to add a tick to the line corresponding to `custno` 250 at the `TrainingDate` `2013-02-26`.

Here's the result of `dput(head(top20CustomersRevenue))`:

```
structure(list(custno = c(250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L), 
    TrainingType = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("In-person", 
    "In person", "In Person", "webinar", "Webinar", "Webinar "
    ), class = "factor"), Revenue = c(4146.8, 6211.93, 2199.72, 
    4452.65, 4787.83, 4004.8), TrainingDate = structure(c(1361865600, 
    1361865600, 1361865600, 1361865600, 1361865600, 1361865600
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), DeltaMonth = structure(c(1357027200, 
    1359705600, 1362124800, 1364799600, 1367391600, 1370070000
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("custno", 
"TrainingType", "Revenue", "TrainingDate", "DeltaMonth"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have this data for 20 different customers with varying `custno` and varying `TrainingDate`.

How do I make sure that the points are on the right lines, and not hanging in the air?

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

@Gregor - Thanks a lot for your extremely helpful answer. I'm still facing an issue with `ceiling_date` though:

Here's a part of my original data:

```
[889] "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01"
[895] "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01"
[901] "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01"
[907] "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01"
```

Here's the same part after running `ceiling_date(top20CustomersRevenue$TrainingDate + months(1), unit = "month")`:

```
[889] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
[895] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
[901] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
[907] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
```

Looking at this code generating `NA`, I ran the following statement and it didn't generate `NA`.

```
> ceiling_date(as.Date("2013-02-01")+months(1),unit="month")
[1] "2013-03-01"
```

Why this difference in behavior? Would you have any idea?

Comment: So far you have not shown the structure of that dataframe or what one might see for a "TrainingType".Presumably you would use a points-layer plotting call with a subset of the data. Details unclear at the moment.

Comment: Sorry for not adding the structure earlier, I know you had pointed it out yesterday. Added it now.

Comment: When we switched to `ceiling_date()` we also deleted the `+ months(1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested right now because I'm answering this while my R session is busy running a model, but I think it'll work:

As @BondedDust suggests, first we'll subset your data, 1 row per customer per training:

```
library(dplyr)
trainingSummary <- top20CustomersRevenue %>% group_by(custno, TrainingDate) %>%
    summarize(Revenue = first(Revenue),
              TrainingType = first(TrainingType))
```

**Edit:** To interpolate the Revenue for a particular training day, we look at the previous month and the next month, and figure out where we are based on how far through the month the training occurred. I converted your POSIX dates to `Date` objects, you can convert back at the end if you want.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

top20CustomersRevenue <- top20CustomersRevenue %>% mutate(DeltaMonth = as.Date(DeltaMonth),
              TrainingDate = as.Date(TrainingDate)) 

trainingSummary <- top20CustomersRevenue %>% 
    group_by(custno, TrainingDate) %>%
    mutate(prev.month.rev = Revenue[DeltaMonth == floor_date(TrainingDate, unit = "month")],
           next.month.rev = Revenue[DeltaMonth == ceiling_date(TrainingDate, unit = "month")],
           interp.rev = prev.month.rev + (next.month.rev - prev.month.rev) * 
               ((mday(TrainingDate) - 1) / days_in_month(month(TrainingDate)))) %>%
    summarize(Revenue = first(interp.rev),
              TrainingType = first(TrainingType))
trainingSummary$TrainingType <- factor(trainingSummary$TrainingType)


p <- ggplot() + 
     geom_line(data = top20CustomersRevenue,
               aes(x = DeltaMonth, y=Revenue, group=custno), alpha=0.3) +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(y = 'Revenue (Dollars)', x = '') +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=0, angle=0), 
          axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=1, angle=45),
          plot.title = element_text(size=20)) +
    geom_point(data = trainingSummary,
               aes(x = TrainingDate, y = Revenue, color= TrainingType))
p
```

[image]

This works well on the sample you provided. If you have any cases where the training occurred after the last DeltaMonth or before the first DeltaMonth, they won't work.

#### Little bit on interpolation:

What we're doing to get the y-value (that is, the Revenue) to plot on a particular training date is pretty simple. Let's say we have a training on date `d`.  We get the y (revenue) values `y_prev` for the previous DeltaMonth, and `y_next` for the next month revenue. 
Since all your DeltaMonth date values are on the first of the month using `floor_date()` and `ceiling_date()` gets us the previous and next DeltaMonth date values.

The slope of the line connecting the previous and next month revenue is

```
slope = change in y / change in x = (y_next - y_prev) / (number of days in month)
```

Therefore the y value for for the the training date is the previous revenue (`y_prev`) plus the slope times the number of days since the start of the month. The number of days since the start of the month is `mday(trainingDate) - 1`, the other stuff in `interp.rev` is the slope. It's just high-school algebra with points and slopes.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I'm getting an error though: `Error in if (sum(c(new$hour, new$min, new$sec))) { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical`, while creating the `trainingSummary` dataframe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795482/error-when-executing-floor-date suggested that I should check for `NA`, I did and I have no NAs. However, while running `top20CustomersRevenue$TrainingDate + months(1)`, I notice that `Jan 30` is getting converted to `Feb 30` which is producing `NA`.

Comment: All the interpolation is doing is looking at the point before the training, looking at the point after the training, and figuring out where the training is on the line connecting those two dots.

Comment: Thanks a lot once again, it makes perfect sense. I was thinking pretty much on similar lines, just didn't know how to do it or that it was called Interpolation.

Comment: `ceiling_date` is still acting pretty funny, I will update my question.